# Matlab XlsRead - is this poorly styled code?

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm trying to read an Excel spreadsheet with the first column having keys and the following columns having values into a struct with the keys as field names and the values as, well, values. I came up with the following code, but it just doesn't feel very matlab-y - I feel like there should be a way to do this in O(1) time rather than O(n).

```
[num,txt,~]=xlsread('whatever.xls','Rate');
txt=cell2mat(txt);
for i = 1:size(txt)
    rates.(txt(i,:))=num(i,:)
end
```

What's a more appropriate way of going about this? I'm working at home, where I only have Octave, so importdata is out of the realm of solutions.

Comment: Just a note on O(n) time: just because certain procedures in Matlab can be written without using `for` or `while` doesn't mean that those procedures have underlying complexity of O(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can structs with various field names and values using the "struct" command in cases like this.  The hardest part is usually getting the cell inputs in the right order... luckily for you, xlsread gives you (almost) what you need.  I'm assuming for now that your excel file looks like:

```
field1  field2  field3
1   2   3
```

If that's the case, then:

```
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('C:\...\xlsx');
myStruct = struct(raw{:});
```

Will work.  That's the magic of cell-array expansion.  Look at the help for "struct", and the help for "cell".  This is good, too:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/21/dealing-with-cells/

Just as a final note, Brian L is correct above; a MATLAB one-liner might look cool, but it's not "guaranteed" to be faster than the corresponding for-loop.

And given that 99% of the time the person reading your code won't be able to make sense of the example above, your for-loop example is just fine.